What is the correct way to configure my npm to download packages from nexus repository?
I'm encountering a challenge while configuring npm to fetch packages from Nexus. Upon attempting to download packages such as axios or express using commands like npm install axios or npm install express, I consistently encounter the error message:
Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
Here are the steps I've taken so far to set up Nexus:
Created a Proxy Repository with default url https://registry.npmjs.org/.
Established a Hosted Repository.
Formed a Group Repository with the Proxy Repository and Hosted Repository included as members.
Created role and user with all read and write access
On the client side, I've meticulously followed these steps:
Initialized npm with npm init.
Set the registry to the URL of the Nexus npm group repository using npm config set registry .
Generated a base64 token using echo -n 'user:pass' | openssl base64 and set it as the authentication token using npm config set _auth="".
Additionally, I attempted to log in to the registry using npm login --registry . While the login process was successful, I encountered the same error upon attempting to download packages.
I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!
